# Is there a link between the two definitions of homogeneity for differential equations (for a first order equation and diff equations of higher order)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations, transformation

According to Wikipedia, there are two definitions for homogeneity of a differential equation. The first is for first order differential equations:

> A first-order ordinary differential equation in the form:
>
> ${\displaystyle M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy=0}$
>
> is a homogeneous type if both functions $M(x, y)$ and $N(x, y)$ are homogeneous functions of the same degree $n$.[1] That is, multiplying each variable by a parameter   ${\displaystyle \lambda }$, we find
>
> ${\displaystyle M(\lambda x,\lambda y)=\lambda ^{n}M(x,y)\,}$,     and     ${\displaystyle N(\lambda x,\lambda y)=\lambda ^{n}N(x,y)\,.} $
>
> Thus,
>   ${\displaystyle {\frac {M(\lambda x,\lambda y)}{N(\lambda x,\lambda y)}}={\frac {M(x,y)}{N(x,y)}}\,.}$

Which to me suggests something about how is we were to rescale each of the axes, the differential equation will remain the same.

Then there is the definition for higher-order equations:

> A linear differential equation is called homogeneous if the following condition is satisfied:
>
> If   ${\displaystyle \phi (x)}$  is a solution, so is   ${\displaystyle c\phi (x)}$, where ${\displaystyle c}$ is an arbitrary (non-zero) constant. Note that in order for this condition to hold, each term in a linear differential equation of the dependent variable y must contain y or any derivative of y. A linear differential equation that fails this condition is called inhomogeneous.
>   A linear differential equation can be represented as a linear operator acting on $y(x)$ where $x$ is usually the independent variable and y is the dependent variable. Therefore, the general form of a linear homogeneous differential equation is
>
> ${\displaystyle L(y)=0\,}$
>
> ...
>
> It should be noted that the existence of a constant term is a sufficient condition for an equation to be inhomogeneous, as in the above example.

So I get that this definition also has something to do with scaling, although it seems to be only scaling the y.

Is there a connection between these two definitions? Are they referring to the same but just with different order equations?